# What's the fastest way to filter a django queryset based on a custom method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that's recursive. Let's call it `Organization`. I have another model that is a child of `Organization` called `Store`.

When `Store`'s are listed in the application it is in a hierarchical format so we actually get the `Organization`'s and include the recursive hierarchy below them. In the serializer we pass in parameters to filter the `Store` and we return `None` if the store does not match the filters.

However, the catch is that the `Organization` will be still be returned even if it has no `Stores` which causes the table to have a bunch of empty pages if the `Store` does not match the filters.

To counter this, in the viewset I want to filter the organizations based on whether or not they will have a store.

`queryset = [x for x in queryset if x.will_have_store()]`

```
def will_have_store(self):
        willHaveStore = False
        for organization in self.organizations.all():
            willHaveStore = organization.will_have_store()
            if (willHaveStore):
                return True
            if (hasattr(organization, 'store') and organization.store.id ):
                willHaveStore = True
        return willHaveStore
```

This is really close to working but it's painfully slow because it does a recursive check on every row in the database for every query. Is there anyway to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with was to filter the stores  that I needed and to get the organizations rather than to filter the organizations based on store properties.

**Filter the stores**
various ways to do this

**Get all the parents of the stores**

```
all_orgs = []
for store in store_queryset:
  all_orgs.push(store.get_all_parents())
```

**Get all the orgs**

```
queryset = Organizations.objects.filter(organization__in=all_orgs)
```

Then return the orgs